# Writing eclipse templates

Tags: django, eclipse, templates, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-templates

I am writing django templates in Eclipse->prefrences->templates, to autocomplete DJango templates. I wrote this

```
{% block ${cursor} %}

{% endblock %}
```

Now, when I request and do autocompletion, after typing `{%` the autocompletion is

```
{% {% block  %}

{% endblock %}
```

While I would like

```
{% block  %}

{% endblock %}
```

With cursor after block. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you've been using a "Code completion" template instead of a Editor template?

Comment: Don't think so.Here is a screenshot. http://uswaretech.com/dump/screenshots/screenshot_016.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of typing `{%` and selecting `dj_for_empty`, try typing `dj_` and then auto-completing. It will behave the way you expect in that case.

**BOTTOM-LINE:** You auto-complete the templates into the editor based on the template name, not based on the template contents.

It appears that autocompletion has two sources: regular HTML tags (for which I can't find the definitions to change anywhere in Eclipse, sorry) and the templates themselves (which you correctly demonstrated in your comment with the screenshot).

Look at this image:

[image]

Instead of typing `<t` and triggering auto-complete, I typed `t`. You can see that there are entries with `<>` - indicating these are autocompletions based on the actual HTML tag - and entries with `#` - indicating these are autocompletions based on a template.

It appears templates are to be accessed by the name of the template. Notice that the template named `table` provides a complete `<table>` and not just the `<table></table>` that is autocompleted if you just type `<tab` and autocompletes.